# How to correctly react conditionally to a Dialog button press?

Tags: dialog, javafx-8

I have a dialog, where after pressing the "OK" button I must validate the input made in the dialog. If validation fails, I want to display an Alert and keep the dialog open.

How do I do this check? If I add a result converter which converts the `ButtonType` to `null` if the conditions are not met, I don't get the wanted behaviour.

By now, I see two possibilities here:

1. I could add an event filter to the respective button:

   ```
   dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(type)
       .addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
           if (conditions not fulfilled) {
               event.consume();
           }
   });
   ```

   This way, the button doesn't fire if the validation fails.
   This seems to be working, but I have the feeling that there must be another way to reach my goal which is closer to the "dialog stuff" itself.
2. Via a close request event.
   Here, the documentation says that the close event only is relevant for "external" close events such as pressing ESC or clicking on the X button in the title bar of the dialog.
   Besides, I have to watch out for resetting the `result` property to `null` before proceeding and for preventing another close.
3. Via any other dialog event.
    Here I haven't found an element which would stop the process when consumed – neither DIALOG_SHOWING not DIALOG_SHOWN nor DIALOG_HIDING nor DIALOG_HIDDEN seem to do the trick.

What am I missing?

Comment: Define *closer to the dialog stuff*. This is how the  what the `DialogPane.createButton` method initializes the event handler: `button.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, ae -> {
            if (ae.isConsumed()) return;
            ... close dialog ...
        });` so there seems to be little you can do besides extending `DialogPane` and overriding the method or sticking to the first approach...

Comment: The first approach is pretty much the one recommended in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) (see the "Dialog Validation / Intercepting Button Actions" section.) Also note that you could use similar techniques to, e.g., disable the button if the input is not valid.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the link. Your comment would make a fine answer.

Comment: As indeed would the comment from @fabian

Comment: @fabian With "closer to the dialog stuff" I meant "not digging so deep into the internals of what `Dialog` tries to wrap away." But as James_D pointed out, this is exactly the recommended way, so I'll do it this way. Thanks!